# Can a script injected into a page by a Chrome Extension access functions in the host page’s bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, bundle

I have a working prototype that successfully calls a function in a js library attached to the host page directly.

I want my Chrome Extension to work on specific domains that have these functions in a bundle.js file. Can I reference bundle.js and its functions from a script injected into host page? If so, how?

Comment: Only if the page script exposes those functions globally or via an object/property accessible from the global context. If it's the case, you can [put your calling code in the page context](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have my script working on the page context I just don’t know how to refer to a function in bundle.js (understanding that the function has to be exposed globally or accessible from the global context). What would the syntax look like?

Comment: Just like any other function call: foo() or foo.bar() or document.querySelector('.CodeMirror').CodeMirror.getValue()

Comment: Ah! Thank you for taking the time to answer - I realize its an obvious question. If I just refer to the function I get a 'function not found' console error. But because of bundle.js I was assuming I had to somehow refer to an abstracted function or something. Or this sort of thing: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2171

Comment: "function not found" means it's not accessible from the global context and the issue you've linked simply says the bundle must explicitly expose stuff that should be exposed. There are no magic workarounds. OTOH depending on how the bundle is organized you can set up an "interceptor" in your content script before the bundle runs and save the references to the internal functions. For example, you can override (aka intercept/spoof) a standard function or API used by something in that bundle.

Comment: Many thanks for your guidance...are there any examples of "intercepting" (sounds scary) you could link to? A quick Google didn't result in any examples...

Comment: It's quite simple per se but too complicated for comments. You can inspect an existing extension like WebAPI Manager.

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to write that as a solution, of sorts? My question wasn't "how do you do it" but "is it possible"...so I think you answered it @wOxxOm